# How do I extend unix “ps -ef” command to see more info

Tags: unix, solaris, sunos

I need to grep process by information containing in CMD column, but this column strings is cut(limited) and needed info is lost. Please suggest how can I enlarge string size allowed for CMD column.

The OS is Solaris 2.1/SunOS 5.1

Comment: add some `w`: `ps efwww`

Comment: man ps is your friend.

Comment: buahahahahahaaha

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic unix/linux knowledge which is not sysadmin-specific.

Comment: The general approach to this problem is to install the BSD version of ps which DOES support the ww flag. In response to the off topic claims, I'd call this a duplicate long before I would call a question concerning a SunOS machine off topic.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589598/extend-ps-output-to-more-than-80-characters-in-solaris-8

Comment: ..In Fact, `/usr/ucb/ps` seems to be installed on our solaris boxes so it might be a default thing. (I'm no solaris master)

NOTE: I got your desired output with `/usr/ucb/ps -aux`

Comment: The correct way to the see the full command line on Solaris is the `pargs` command (doesn't exist on Linux, is a Solaris thing). The Solaris `ps` command will get you only so far as it doesn't support the Linux-specific `-w` or `-ww` options. You'll come to enjoy the `pargs` command because it produces output you can easily parse.

Answer (score 1):

`ps -efww` will not restrict the width of a line.

`w` means "wide". `ww` means "unlimited width".

Comment: I got next trying this: ps: illegal option -- w

Comment: @user590444: What OS are you on? "Unix" tell us next to nothing.

Comment: uname says : SunOS 5.1

Comment: This works on Linux. Read the manual page `man ps` and try some options listed there, that's all I did.